# Android: Back navigation to not yet called activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, toolbar

I have an **Activity A** which is showing up on startup of the App.

Activity A calls an **Activity B** via an intent.

Activity B has a toolbar with a back/home navigation button defined.

In the AndroidManifest it is defined that the parent activity of activity B is an **Activity C**.

However, rather than showing Activity C the app terminates when the back navigation button is touched. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.com.testlauncher">

    <application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <activity android:name=".C">
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".A" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".B"
            android:parentActivityName=".C">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="test.com.testlauncher.C" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

B.java

```
public class B extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.B);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setTitle("Back");

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

B.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The android Documentation on [Implementing Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral#java) clearly states:

> To navigate up when the user presses the app icon, you can use the `NavUtils` class's static method, `navigateUpFromSameTask()`. When you call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward. The way it is brought forward depends on whether the parent activity is able to handle an onNewIntent() call:
>
> - If the parent activity has launch mode `<singleTop>`, or the up intent
>     contains `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, the parent activity is brought to
>     the top of the stack, and receives the intent through its
>     `onNewIntent()` method.

Hence in order to navigate to Parent Activity on Back Navigation, add `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` onBackPressed.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Also when the line  NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); is used in onOptionsItemSelected() within the switch-case "android.R.id.home".